# jQuery select 'this' and another selector at same time

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

I am using a jQuery click function and would like to know if I can use the term 'this' to select the nav element and another selector at the same here's my code:

```
$('#nav').click(function() {
    $(this, '#anotherSelector').hide();
});
```

This doesn't work. It selects the `#anotherSelector` and not the `#nav` element as well. What am I doing wrong?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use [`.add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/) to add another selector into your set of elements you want to deal with, like this:

```
$('#nav').click(function() {
    $(this).add('#anotherSelector').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `$(this).add('#anotherSelector').hide();` instead.

See [add](http://api.jquery.com/add)

What you've got at the moment reads as "search for the DOM element (this), that is inside the element whose ID is anotherSelector."; see [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [add()](http://api.jquery.com/add/) function to extend your selection

```
$(this).add('#anotherSelector').hide();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#nav').click(function() {
    $('#nav, #anotherSelector').hide();
});
```